# MongoDB error during "sudo pacman update" in manjaro linux terminal

Tags: mongodb, terminal, manjaro

When I tried to update my packages in manjaro linux using the command : sudo pacman update , I got this error which says that database does not exists and database is already registered , can any one knows any potential solution to this problem :

warning: database file for 'mongodb' does not exist (use '-Sy' to download)
error: could not register 'mongodb' database (database already registered)
error: no operation specified (use -h for help)

I have tried removing the whole mongodb from system but that didnt work either.

Comment: You can try cleaning the package cache `sudo pacman -Scc` then try it again and update your system `sudo pacman -Syu`